# Svn and disconnected edits

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am using svn (VisualSVN Server in specific with VisualSVN and thus TortoiseSVN). Is it possible to work in an offline scenario? E.g. code is checked in, and then modify the solution without checking out the relevant file?

What (if anything) will go wrong?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934208/working-offline-with-svn-on-local-machine-temporary

Answer (score 1):

You can work offline with local repository through **file://**. First you need to create local repo, sync with remote, then switch working dir to the local repo, after some work you can sync them back with remote and switch working dir back to remote. This is described [here](http://www.henrynestler.com/colinux/tools/howto-svn-offline.txt).

Answer (score 1):

You can continue working, but ...

Some svn actions still can be completed while you're not connected to repo. For example - svn diff, to see your local changes, svn st. This is possible since while you checkout, svn save copy of each checkout file in .svn.

Actions that require access to repo can not be accomplished - e.g. svn commit.

Answer (score 0):

No, SVN requires access to a centralized server.  You cannot queue up commits offline for later transmission to the server.

You may find what you need with a distributed version control system such as [Mercurial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQFjAB&url=http://mercurial.selenic.com/&ei=TfJfTp7dJJTksQKd8twr&usg=AFQjCNF7tD0P7fC99C8kD2nopBTgsWdp3Q&sig2=Z9AKtkF8Crnfrr_j59Wgcw) or [Git](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://git-scm.com/&ei=SvJfTqSaG6GpsAKfyewM&usg=AFQjCNHBOAWIJWLQ6wmj_GErAgGzWCkTbA&sig2=BsXW5K7qWk5fW7udW44K_g).  They allow you to work offline as if you were connected, and then synch your changes when you eventually connect.